# Get element position out of matrix1 in order to remove every element with the founded position in matrix2

Tags: r

i have the following test-code here

```
test1 = tibble::tribble(
          ~name1,      ~name2, ~name3, ~name4, ~name5,
          "C452",          NA,     NA,     NA,     NA,
          "D622",      "M245",     NA,     NA,     NA,
          "J533",      "J625",     NA,     NA,     NA,
          "F226",      "L325",     NA,     NA,     NA,
          "B565",      "F226",     NA,     NA,     NA,
          "W342", "DUPLICATE",     NA,     NA,     NA,
          "H452",      "K632", "L553", "DUPLICATE", "R551",
          "C636",      "J245", "DUPLICATE",     NA,     NA,
          "H525",          NA,     NA,     NA,     NA
          )



test2 = tibble::tribble(
              ~name1,      ~name2,  ~name3,        ~name4,   ~name5,
           "MICHAEL",          NA,      NA,            NA,       NA,
         "ALEXANDER",    "GEORGE",      NA,            NA,       NA,
              "CHUN", "KNAPPWOST",      NA,            NA,       NA,
              "CIRO",     "SIMON",      NA,            NA,       NA,
             "ARMIN",      "CIRO",      NA,            NA,       NA,
           "JUERGEN",   "JUERGEN",      NA,            NA,       NA,
            "EDWARD",   "PHILIPP",   "TRU", "CHRISTOPHER", "VICTOR",
           "RAPHAEL", "CHRISTOPH", "JAMES",            NA,       NA,
             "NILES",          NA,      NA,            NA,       NA
         )

###GETS THE LIST OF ELEMENTS THAT ARE DUPLICATES
position = grep('DUPLICATE',test1)

###THAT IS WHAT I WANT
gsub(position, 'DUPLICATE', test2)
```

I always get a warning and don't know how to fix that.
At the end I want to go threw lets say a big matrix1, find the position of every 'DUPLICATE' and remove elements in matrix2 with the exact position (row,column) from the 'DUPLICATES' found in matrix1.

Probably really easy but I cannot figure it out somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy to do if you convert the data to dataframes.

```
test1 <- data.frame(test1)
test2 <- data.frame(test2)

test1[test1 == 'DUPLICATE' & !is.na(test1)] <- test2[test1 == 'DUPLICATE' & !is.na(test1)]
test1

#  name1   name2 name3       name4 name5
#1  C452    <NA>  <NA>        <NA>  <NA>
#2  D622    M245  <NA>        <NA>  <NA>
#3  J533    J625  <NA>        <NA>  <NA>
#4  F226    L325  <NA>        <NA>  <NA>
#5  B565    F226  <NA>        <NA>  <NA>
#6  W342 JUERGEN  <NA>        <NA>  <NA>
#7  H452    K632  L553 CHRISTOPHER  R551
#8  C636    J245 JAMES        <NA>  <NA>
#9  H525    <NA>  <NA>        <NA>  <NA>
```

Comment: thanks for your help. That is almost it but now I wanted it the other way around. So basically to copy the 'DUPLICATE' from test1 into test2.

Comment: That would be `test2[test1 == 'DUPLICATE' & !is.na(test1)] <- 'DUPLICATE'`

Answer (score 0):

We can use [**`dplyr`**](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) and there is no need to convert back to `data.frame`.  Just use `mutate` with `across`, extract the corresponding column from 'test2' based on the column name (`cur_column()`) and change the elements that are 'DUPLICATE' with the corresponding 'test2' column in `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
test1 <- test1 %>% 
    mutate(across(everything(),
      ~ case_when(. %in% 'DUPLICATE' ~ test2[[cur_column()]], TRUE ~ .)))
```

-output

```
test1
# A tibble: 9 x 5
  name1 name2   name3 name4       name5
  <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr>       <chr>
1 C452  <NA>    <NA>  <NA>        <NA> 
2 D622  M245    <NA>  <NA>        <NA> 
3 J533  J625    <NA>  <NA>        <NA> 
4 F226  L325    <NA>  <NA>        <NA> 
5 B565  F226    <NA>  <NA>        <NA> 
6 W342  JUERGEN <NA>  <NA>        <NA> 
7 H452  K632    L553  CHRISTOPHER R551 
8 C636  J245    JAMES <NA>        <NA> 
9 H525  <NA>    <NA>  <NA>        <NA>
```